# Parable for an impossible idea or business plan

Tags: analogy, example, story

[Edit: I have asked the wrong question—my apologies. What I am looking for is not a single word, expression, or idiom. I am looking for a parable or an example of an analogy. Maybe a one-sentence, real-life story of a well-known instance where megalomania meets idiocy.]

Occasionally people get excited over some business plan or idea in general, talking exaltedly about the outcomes or benefits, ignoring some crucial logical hole or contradicting physical laws.

Example:

> Executive: Now if we get the response time for our signal to Australia below 50ms we have won.
>   Engineer: But the speed-of-light limit to Australia is 67ms.
>   Executive: Yes, it is a problem but we must not give up now.

Are there any canonical parables or examples of analogies for this concept?

Comment: Hi, I am not looking for a word choice or 'one word for'. In the FAQ it says "Questions asking for help expressing a concept or an idea" are on topic.

Comment: Except, you're not asking for help Writing a new metaphor, you're asking about if there is an existing one in the English Language to Use.  While I admit there is overlap and interplay, I feel that the pool of people on ELU is better suited to answering (although, again, there is overlap between the two)

Comment: You have two good answers here. Are they more in line with what you are after? I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

An established expression for this is **pie in the sky**:

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pie%20in%20the%20sky):

> : an unrealistic enterprise or prospect of prosperity

And from [Lexico (Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pie_in_the_sky), which provides example sentences:

> Used to describe or refer to something that is pleasant to contemplate but is very unlikely to be realized.
>
> ‘It's probably pie in the sky to say we could unionize them, but that's what I'd like to see.’
> ‘We are not talking pie in the sky, we are talking about clear correlations which will help deliver a healthier Scotland.’
> ‘We are still in the preliminary stages but we are seriously interested - it is not pie in the sky.’

So, to rephrase the example dialogue in the question:

> Engineer: But the speed-of-light limit to Australia is 67ms, so this is just *pie in the sky*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expression ***[castles in the air](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/castles-in-the-air)*** meaning:

> plans that have very little chance of happening.

Cambridge Dictionary)